# Multipart form $_FILES array is empty after submission, but files upload

Tags: php, arrays, file-upload, multipartform-data

I have a multipart form in which I allow the user to select multiple files which is placed in an array. Here is a scaled down portion of my code:

```
<form id="fileupload" action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
</form>
```

In my **upload.php** file, I want to write to a text file and place info from each file (doesn't matter how it's formatted, array is fine).

```
$date = $_POST["date"];
$files = $_POST["files"];


$myFile = $date . ".txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("cant_open_file");
$stringData = "Date: " . $date . "\n";
$stringData .= "Uploaded Files:\n";
$stringData .=  $file; // prints nothing?
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
```

However, nothing is **`$file`** is printing nothing.

### Question

How can I print the file info for each file that is chosen from the user into my text file?

### Desired output

```
Date: Todays Date
Files: 2 file(s)
    File: someimage1.png
    Size: 10KB

    File: someimage1.png
    Size: 20KB
```

### Update

For some reason, **`$_FILES['files']`** is blank when submitted but I when I use the preceding example, **"File: " and "Size: "** print out, but **`$file['name']`** and **`$file['size']`** seem to be blank. Also, say I choose 3 files, "File/Size" is printed 5 times (suggesting that 5 files were chosen). This is the same for any amount of files chosen. I've made sure the correct values are in **php.ini** as well. Not sure where to go from here.

```
foreach($files as $file){
    $stringData .=  "   File: ".$file['name']."\n"; // return blank
    $stringData .=  "   Size: ".$file['size']."\n"; // return blank
}
```

Also, I am using [**jQuery File Upload Demo**](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/).

Answer (score 4):

Use `$files = $_FILES["files"];` to get the uploaded file information.

[POST method uploads](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)

Answer (score 1):

You can use loop in the `$_FILES` array:

```
foreach($files as $file){
    $stringData .=  "File: ".$file['name']."\n";
    $stringData .=  "Size: ".$file['size']."\n";
}
```

make sure you use [move_uploaded_file()](http://uk.php.net/move_uploaded_file) because you only store them in `/tmp` folder and you will lose them.

Comment: Okay, so a little progress made. Now i get "File: " and "Size: " but `$file['name']` and `$file['size']` seem to be blank. Also, say I choose 3 files, "File/Size" is printed 5 times (suggesting that 5 files were chosen. Not sure what thats all about.

Comment: Actually, it' doesn't matter how many files I select, it always shows as 5 files. Any idea why that would be?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$files = $_FILES['files'];

echo "<pre>";
print_r($files);
```

instead of

```
$files = $_POST["files"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try using `$_FILES` as follows instead of `$_POST['files']`:

print_r($_FILES['files'])